# How can I increase the amount of tourists arriving from the Ferry Terminal?

Tags: simcity-2013

I've put a Ferry Terminal (with Cruise Ship Dock) and a casino right next to it. Sadly, there seems to be very few tourists arriving through the ferry. Is there any way to increase the amount? The Bus Terminal at the other casino seems to bring in loads of tourists.

Comment: What type of casino is next to the dock and which add-ons do you have?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem may be you don't have any connecting cities with ferry docks to bring in tourists from other cities. If this is the case I suspect this could be limiting you but cannot say 100%.

[image: Ferry Connection]

Here's some related information about casinos and tourists in general (VERY HELPFUL):

http://www.reddit.com/r/SimCityStrategy/comments/1aa66p/the_skinny_on_tourism_and_gambling/

Answer (score -1):

[image: Ferry]

Hi -- going by the visual description the dock is for commuters 'only'. You'll want to have the Cruise Ship add-on to get the Medium/High Wealth Tourists.

Comment: I have the Cruise Ship Dock, I updated my question with clarification.

Comment: How close is the terminal do your casinos? ie: I found it worked a lot better having a street car line directly there...